# How to search roman numerals in string with dart language?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter. i have a string which have some roman numbers that indicate steps.. so i want to arrange that steps with new line and don't know how to do it. i tried `string.replaceAll()` but cannot get it since there are many roman number and some of then are the same such as **i** and **ii**. for example i have this string..

```
String text = 'some text here i) some step 1 ii) some step 2 iii) some step 3. some text after step blabla '
```

I want the output to have '\n' infront of the roman number which will arrange the output

**some text here**
**i) some step 1**
**ii) some step 2**
**iii) some step 3**

**some text after step blabla**

is there something i can use to detect the numeral numbers and add '\n' infront of it in the string or is there some other way.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a simpler way to do this with some sort of regex that I don't know about, but something like this should work.

```
String text = 'Your String'
List<String> words = text.split(' ');
String result = '';
for(var word in words){
    if(word.endsWith(')')){
        result += word + '\n';
    }else{
        result += word
    }
}
//result now contains the desired string
```

Comment: yeah i prefer reget to since there is a list of string stored and some of them does not have the steps, but i dont know how to use the regex

Comment: i found the regex expression which is [link](https://regex101.com/r/tYZTnE/3)  . but how to use it on dart?

Answer (score 1):

Tricky to know when "**some text after step blabla**" should have line breaks in front because I don't know what to look for... That you would have to specify more closely.

Using the [Numerus package](https://pub.dev/packages/numerus) to check for valid Roman Numeral.

Have this a go:

```
      String text = 'some text here i) some step 1 ii) some step 2 iii) some step 3. ao) invalid roman numberal. some textafter';
      RegExp regexp = new RegExp(r"((\w+)\))");

      final stringWithLinebreaks = text.replaceAllMapped(regexp, (match) {
        return match.group(2).isValidRomanNumeral()
            ? '\n${match.group(1)}'
            : '${match.group(1)}';
      });
      print(stringWithLinebreaks);
```

That will print out:

```
some text here 
i) some step 1 
ii) some step 2 
iii) some step 3. ao) invalid roman numberal. some textafter
```

You could of course make it better in several ways. Such as converting the roman numeral to int value using `toRomanNumeralValue()`, then sorting the steps accordingly if they are in the incorrect order in the text string. You could also make the RegExp more precise in several ways. For instance replacing `\w` with `[iIvVxXlLcCdDmM]` and so on..

Answer (score 0):

i've found the answer from javascript and modify some of it... this is my answer... but i managed to search roman number from 1 to 10 only.. but its ok since the step never exceed more than 10

```
String formatText(String text) {
RegExp regExp = new RegExp(r'(?:viii?|i(?:ii?|[vx])?|vi?|x)\)');
String value = text.replaceAllMapped(regExp, (match) => "\n${match.group(0)}");
return value;
}
```

Comment: This can work as well, but I mean, if you include the Numberus package I wrote about above, then my solution will handle all roman numerals. It is basically the same code except that instead of always returning "\n${match.group(0)}" you include an if-statement. So imo this answer is inferiour.

Comment: @RobertSandberg I would argue this is the best solution because the regex could be modified to support more roman numerals if necessary and it removes the need for a dependency. A dependency so niche is unlikely to be well maintained.

Comment: @EmmettDeen It is purely speculative that it is "unlikely" to be well maintained. How do you know? Nevertheless, the code in that package is on the brink of trivial so if the user needs to maintain it himself that would be straight forward. What is done in that package is basically exactly what you suggest, "regex could be modified..." RegExp(r'^(M{0,65})(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$') And if the user does that by himself, then he does what someone already did. Isn't one of the purposes of packages and open source to avoid that..